# Call javascript file from another javascript program

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript program which use another javascript program : I want to call this JS file from my Javascript program.
How can i do this without need of html ?

Comment: are your js files have same origin (located at the same domain) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes my files have same origin

Comment: ok. Now you can explain what are you intending in "calling" one js file from another: do you want to load the content of external js script to your current js file OR you want just organize data exchange between two js files ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have a javascript program, and some functions from my js program are implemented in other javascript files : so my js program need other js files and js librairies to be well executed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer posted here:

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

You could always just combine the files into one .js

Comment: But i have to require js libraries which can be updated